# What is this PoolAllocator in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When run my module in a session it gives messages which are coming from tensorflow poolallocator. Ex:

***I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 1656 get requests, put_count=1249 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.800641 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.910024***

Comment: I went through that. But I would like for a nice introduction. Since tensorflow documentation has nothing much on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret Poolallocator messages in tensorflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151207/how-to-interpret-poolallocator-messages-in-tensorflow)